# Can a JNDI lookup in a Servlet cause a permgen memory leak?

Tags: java, servlets, jboss, jndi, permgen

Since JBoss 4.2 does not support @EJB injections, I am using a JNDI lookup to reference an EJB that is needed by a Servlet.

I am concerned that this type of lookup may be causing the Permgen non-heap memory in the JVM to grow.

As I understand JNDI, it is a form of dynamic classloading, so this might be causing a classloader leak.

So my question is, could the below servlet code possibly be causing a Permgen memory leak over time?

Also, should I be explicitly calling the close() method on InitialContext after the lookup?  Is there a chance that GC is not cleaning up the InitialContexts as expected due to the way they are being instantiated here (in a Servlet)?

Thank you.

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

// JBoss 4.x does not support @EJB injections in servlets (see jndi lookup below)
@EJB
private MyService myService;

private static final String SERVICE_JNDI_NAME = "MyServiceBean";

private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getPackage().getName());


public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

try {
    // JBoss 4.x does not support @EJB injections in servlets
    InitialContext ctx = new javax.naming.InitialContext();
    myService = (MyService) ctx.lookup(SERVICE_JNDI_NAME);
} catch (NamingException e) {
    log.warn("NamingException trying to lookup MyService in context");
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}

...

RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/page.jsp");
requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
}
```

}

Comment: so what is stopping you from increasing permgen memory, as it obviously is running out? Always add finally block with context close.

Comment: Hi Thomas, increasing the permgen upper limit will not help since the current leak continues to increase incrementally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JNDI](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/jndi/index.html) is a directory lookup service and a core technology of Java Enterprise Edition application servers. Unless you have a buggy implementation or have an application with an unusual usage pattern, then I would expect the classes loaded because of JNDI to stabilize eventually.

Either way, I strongly recommend you to use a [heap dump analyzer](http://www.alphaworks.ibm.com/tech/heapanalyzer). Take several snapshots while your application is running and see what is added when the permgen keeps increasing. This information will either show you directly what the problem is, or help narrow down the root cause to a much smaller area.

Comment: Thanks Kim.  The leak is only occurring in a production system to which access is very limited.  Additionally the server is running Java 1.5 and jmap and jhat are not installed, so currently heap dump options are limited.  Also, from what I have been reading about permgen leaks, a heap dump will supply limited useful info about the contents of the non-heap permgen memory.  Nevertheless, I do realize that I am going to need to figure out some way to get at the contents of the leaking permgen.

Comment: Yes, your options with Java 1.5 and earlier are more limited. Keep in mind that a common cause of permgen problems are leaking class loaders. Abuse of String.intern() could also be a possible root cause